# Is it possible to increase the console font size?

Tags: dota-2

Is there any way to increase the console's font size? My resolution is 1920x1080 so the  font size is very small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

1 - Navigate to this folder: `steamapps\common\dota 2 beta\dota`

2 - Locate this file : `pak01_dir.vpk`

3 - Open this file with a text editor, Notepad++ is a great free software for this.

4 - Find (CTRL+F) `"ConsoleText"` in this said file, it should look something like this (in my file, it's at line 46771:

```
"ConsoleText"
{
    "1"
    {
        "name"      "Lucida Console"
        "tall"      "10" // This is the font size.
        "weight"    "500"
    }
}
```

Now simply change the `tall` attribute to something that suit you, perhaps 15.

Before performing any changes to this file, it's always a good idea to create a copy of it if something goes wrong even if the manipulations are quite simple.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Most OS X editors fail to edit the (mostly binary) file properly. Editing with sublime or even nano broke the file. Using a proper hex editor worked just fine.